# Troubleshooting Enso Commands

Tags: launcher

I have some Enso commands that tell me `An error occurred when trying to open <X>.` I'm not sure why. Usually, this is because Enso's shortcut doesn't have the `Start In` attribute set to the correct directory.

But this is not the problem in this case. How can I troubleshoot and fix this problem? I've tried already unlearning and relearning the command a couple of times, manually adding the shortcut, changing `Start In`, etc. but nothing seems to be helping.

Comment: What is your environment? I'm having the same issue with some programs in Win7 while XP worked fine.

Comment: @Jawa I'm on Win7 as well.